# Endlessly turning webcam On and Off?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have wrote a code that will capture pictures eventually and will terminate when after it reaches a certain time.
But once the script is over(i.e after terminating the code using time) how will i re-run automatically after a few seconds.?

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture.set(3,640)
capture.set(4,480)
img_counter = 0
frame_set = []
start_time = time.time()

while(True):
    ret , frame = capture.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frame_set.append(gray)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed = end_time - start_time
    img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
    cv2.imwrite(img_name,gray)
    print("{} written!".format(img_counter))
    img_counter +=1
    if elapsed > 1:
        break
capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code will save images into a folder and get terminated after a few seconds. How will i set it automatically to re-run the code after a few minutes to capture a few more images again ?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: What OS are you on? If Windows we could add the script in a Task Scheduler

Comment: OS : Windows... But is there any other way ? Like inside the code itself to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on windows, you could add the `.py` script in the Task Scheduler and give it a time to run, [described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140110/running-python-script-in-task-scheduler-script-will-not-run):

However if you want to do it within your python file, there are several ways.

First Approach:

Lock the timer, instead of `break`-ing out of the loop.

Something like:

```
import time
starttime=time.time()
while True:
  print("tick every 3 seconds")
  time.sleep(3)
```

So your code should be:

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture.set(3,640)
capture.set(4,480)
img_counter = 0
frame_set = []
start_time = time.time()

while(True):
ret , frame = capture.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
frame_set.append(gray)
cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
end_time = time.time()
elapsed = end_time - start_time
img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
cv2.imwrite(img_name,gray)
print("{} written!".format(img_counter))
img_counter +=1
if elapsed > 1:            
   capture.release()
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   time.sleep(3)
```

Second Approach:

Using [Twisted, which is an event-driven networking engine written in Python.](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/),

```
from twisted.internet import task, reactor

timeout = 60.0 # Sixty seconds

def doWork():
    #do work here
    pass

l = task.LoopingCall(doWork)
l.start(timeout) # call every sixty seconds

reactor.run()
```

In this case, you don't need a time lock:

```
from twisted.internet import task, reactor
import cv2
import time
import numpy

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture.set(3,640)
capture.set(4,480)
img_counter = 0
frame_set = []
start_time = time.time()

timeout = 60.0 # Sixty seconds

def doWork():
    while (True):
        ret, frame = capture.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        frame_set.append(gray)
        cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        end_time = time.time()
        elapsed = end_time - start_time
        img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(img_counter)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, gray)
        print("{} written!".format(img_counter))
        img_counter += 1
        if elapsed > 1:
            break
    capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows())

l = task.LoopingCall(doWork)
l.start(timeout) # call every sixty seconds

reactor.run()
```

> Note: Since your are capturing pictures and will terminating the
>   script after it reaches a certain time, you need to sync the `timeout`
>   in this case with your `elapsed` time to make sure it does not
>   collide. i.e. if the script is capturing pictures for 5 minutes then
>   the timeout should be greater than that. In other words, Run the
>   script after uhm, let's say 7 minutes and it will take 5 minutes for
>   capturing the pictures.